# Can´t use guid as parameter in angular route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to use a guid like this as a parameter in my angular route: (C1A7C09B-22E1-8545-409E-418B5C7F284C)

However angular doesn´t seem to accept them. If I navigate to localhost:4200/(C1A7C09B-22E1-8545-409E-418B5C7F284C) I´ll get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'C1A7C09B-22E1-8545-409E-418B5C7F284C'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'C1A7C09B-22E1-8545-409E-418B5C7F284C'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2270)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2254)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27425)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

That´s my router module:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([{
      path: ":guid",
      component: AppComponent
    }])
```

Comment: Did you get an answer or solution?

Comment: Only a workaround. It can parse the guid so you can use it in your application even though it looks kinda weird for users. Add the following to the @NgModule declaration: providers: [{
    provide: UrlSerializer,
    useClass: StandardUrlSerializer
  }]

This is the class StandardUrlSerializer: https://pastebin.com/bfd4fV0j